# Zend 2, Doctrine 2 Entity validator

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

### Single field validaton

Is it possible to check if a value already exists in another entity? So when a username already exists, a new user can't get that username. In doctrine 2, there are some validators which checks for object existence or unique objects (don't know if a ZF2 validator can use this?). How can I put that in my `inputFilter` so usernames can't be duplicated? I have the following inputFilter for my username right now:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'username',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array( array(
                        'name' => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min' => 3,
                            'max' => 50,
                ),
            ),
        ),
 )));
```

Is it possible to extend this validator with a doctrine-validator, so I can check if there are duplicated usernames?

### Multiple field validation

Currently I'm catching the DBAlException, to see if something went wrong, but in this case I would like to have a message returned of what went wrong, like duplicated key or unique constraints being invalid. So a message at the field which went wrong.

```
try {
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
            } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Duplicate key, please set another name for user.');
return array(
  'form' => $form,
'flashMessages' => $this->flashMessenger()->getCurrentMessages()
                );
}
```

By catching a DBAlException you can't see which unique key(s) are invalid. For example: I've got a Category Entity with the following `Unique Constraint -> uq_ParentId_Name`. How can I check if this constraint is valid for a new (Category) Entity?

Comment: I am too lazy to write an answer right now, so please read this: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md

Comment: Ok, that helped me a little.. But I have my inputFilter in my entity. How can I call my repository from my entity?

Comment: Doctrine Entities should be as dump as possible. POPOs, so to speak. A Model can have InputFilters, a Model could also be injected with the ServiceManager, but a Doctrine Entity should be nothing more than a Data-Object. Your approach simply won't work out for your current needs ;)

Comment: Ah ok, so a option would be to put this validator in my userForm?

Comment: Yep either in form as InputFilterProvider or as standalone InputFilterClass

Answer (score 0):

Check Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists. For example, you want a company name to be unique:

```
new NoRecordExists( array(
    'adapter' => $serviceManager->get( 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' ),
    'table' => 'COMPANY',
    'field' => 'NAME',
    'message' => 'The company name already exists'
);
```

You have to attach it to the desired input, and the message will be related to it.

Comment: @Haidy This validator is not using Doctrine2, it's using the PDO driver directly (which is also used by Doctrine2 when it needs to work with the database). No, you can't use entities. It tests if a record exists against a table of a database. Check the [doc](http://unofficial-zf2.readthedocs.org/en/test/modules/zend.validator.db.html)